# Is it possible to identify in an AJAX error when the user has Stopped the Browser?

Tags: javascript, ajax

How can I identify when a user has simply stopped the loading of the page so that my ajax errors don't display?

Answer (score 0):

Catching onError event maybe?

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp